# Back arrow not visible on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am implementing the following code which inherits AppCompatActivity but I can't see the back arrow on Action Bar.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

[image]

I also want to know about how to make the Title Text Left Align.

Comment: Is the image what you have at the moment, or what you'd like to have?

Comment: can you share all code and theme

Comment: `public  class SettingsPreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    }`

Comment: `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>`

Comment: consider use toolbar and check my answer

Comment: @AlexMoiseenkov, could you update your question with the code you add in comment. And explain what is _not available_ for you (not visible, not functionnal, not responding, ... ) For the second question, well you should look that on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow button should be present for easier navigation. [image: Providing Up Navigation] .

It is easy to do this, see [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) for a short guide.

Answer (score 2):

on your style use

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

and use support toolbar as android suggest

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

For back button this is all you should do

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You can customize title this way

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
     />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and on your code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// Remove default title text
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// Get access to the custom title view
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Comment: I know all this. I just want to understand what the problem is. Because another class this method works. And there is no difference between classes.

Answer (score 0):

In the android Manifest, inside the `activity` tag where your toolbar is, add this meta-tag and the `parentActivityName` property to inform the activity of its parent, and the system will provide an up button to go in the previous activity.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" 
          android:parentActivityName=".TheParentActivity">
       <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
               android:value=".TheParentActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Change `YourActivity` and `TheParentActivity` with your activities.

Finally, enable the up button in your activity's code:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Hope it can help!